# Foreign Earned Income Exclusion (FEIE) and future qualifications

Tags: united-states, taxes

I've used the FEIE in the past and haven't had any issues.  TurboTax is now telling me that since I left the US in July, and thus don't have 330 days required for the physical presence test yet, that I can't claim the exclusion and should file an extension.

I think I remember filing in the past with the intent to remain out of the country until the physical presence test qualification was met, and applying the exclusion only in part (across the days for that tax year that I was out of the US, as opposed to the whole year).

I interpret IRS documents I've looked at online to agree that I can claim the extension for the partial tax year since I intend to remain out of the country until the physical presence test requirement is met.

Should I file an extension and do my taxes when the 330 days elapses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I file an extension and do my taxes when the 330 days elapses?

Yes. If you want to qualify by days count then the days must have passed, you can't rely on future plans.